# Using multiple workspaces in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, workspace

I'm a beginner in using `arcpy`, and having trouble with the following code. I have 2 different input feature layers in different folder. I would like to create a new gdb in the `output_folder` (this works). I get the spatial reference from the Sentinel image, which I use to project and copy new files into the new gdb, but I get an error message in line: `arcpy.env.workspace= ujgdb`

How can I fix it?

```py
infc1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
infc2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Sentinel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
output_folder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
#spatial reference
arcpy.env.workspace= Sentinel
inraster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")[0]
spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(inraster).SpatialReference
ujgdb= arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder, "DEM.gdb")
arcpy.env.workspace= ujgdb
spatialkont= arcpy.Describe(infc1).SpatialReference
if spatialkont.Name == spatialRef.Name:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc1, "kontur_utm")
elif spatialkont.Name =="GCS_WGS_1984":
    arcpy.Project_management(infc1, "kontur_utm", spatialRef)
spatialmag= arcpy.Describe(infc2).SpatialReference
if spatialmag.Name == spatialRef.Name:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(infc2, "magassag_utm")
elif spatialmag.Name =="GCS_WGS_1984":
    arcpy.Project_management(infc2, "magassag_utm", spatialRef)
```

Comment: What is the full error message, including line number, from running the code that you have presented?

Comment: While testing I suggest that you put print statements after each GetParameterAsText so you can be sure that they are set to what you think they are.  Then comment out the GetParameterAsText  (and the print statement) and hardwire each variable to what you saw printed.  That will give us a lot more information about your problem.

Comment: DEM.gdb is created, spatialRef is good. If I run the if statement in the python window is ok. So I think the problem is the new gdb as a workspace.

Comment: Even if your hunch is right, we cannot see what value you chose for that parameter.  Try adding the print (arcpy.AddMessage) statements that I suggested in my last comment.

Comment: Please always include error messages as formatted text rather than pictures.

Comment: The create file geodatabase tool does not return a workspace or string, **ujgdb= arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder, "DEM.gdb")** should be changed to **arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder, "DEM.gdb")** followed by **ujgdb= os.path.join(output_folder, "DEM.gdb")** - don't forget to **import os** first.  Most of the code can be simplifed by setting **arcpy.env.outputSpatialReference = spatialRef** https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Output_Coordinate_System/001w00000005000000/ then copy features will automatically project when/if required.

Comment: To compliment @MichaelStimson, geoprocessing tools return RESULT objects, you are making the assumption that `ujgdb` is a path to the created file geodatabase. Which when fed into the environment setting workspace makes no sense. Explore the help file on RESULT objects.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach when you understand that geoprocessing tools return [Result objects](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/result.htm) is this:

```py
resObj = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(output_folder, "DEM.gdb")
arcpy.env.workspace= resObj.getOutput(0)
```